# Process Automation Specialist Super Badge. Workflow rule migration. Unit: Map your workflow actions to process actions. Failure

Tags: trailhead

Module: Workflow rule migration.
Unit: Map your workflow actions to process actions.

Working on my Process Automation Specialist Super Badge.  With this error I can't move forward.  I have tried using two separate ORGs.  No internet searches have been helpful. There should be nothing difficult about this step but it keeps failing after many iterations.

This is the error:

> Challenge not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
>   We found an opportunity that's associated with a Banking account and updated the stage to Closed Won, but a task wasn't created for the account owner to complete 7 days from today. Make sure that the Closed Won and Banking criteria node and its associated action are configured correctly.

Criteria that fails is 'Closed Won and Banking'.

I have an immediate action creating a new task record with the following fields set.  I have also tried it using a schedule action. Both results are the same.

'Due Date Only'  set to formula `TODAY + 7`
'Subject'        set to "Follow up on account."
'Assigned to ID' set to many combinations but I believe it should be
 `opportunity.accountID.ownerID` or `opportunity.accountID.ownerID.userID`. Nothing succeeds.

Would appreciate any input from those who have completed this step.

Answer (score 0):

Your Assigned To can simply be `Opportunity.OwnerId`.

Make sure that your Process Builder is configured as Trailhead directs, so that *both* of your criteria nodes are evaluated for each record. If you don't do this configuration, you'll see a "STOP" sign at the right-hand side of your first criterion, which is probably "Closed Won". In that situation, records that match that first criterion will never proceed to be evaluated against the second.

Comment: David,  Thank you for your reply.  I finally determined the problem to be the object I was using to determine if the account industry was banking.  The error message lead me in the wrong direction.  I finally had success late yesterday.

Comment: Thanks David, Just had to change to evaluate to next criteria and mine passed.